# change svn file property on the fly with svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I need to change the value of a versioned custom property of a file in an svn repository on the fly.
I do not want to alter any content, just change the value of the property of the already existing file.
I am using svnkit in java.

How would i go about it?

```
example: 
http:://svnserver.com/example/directorya/file1.txt   ... has svn property: myproperty = abc

after the operation:
http:://svnserver.com/example/directorya/file1.txt   ... has svn property: myproperty = def
```

This is what i tried, but it doesnt work. Instead of changing the file property it adds a commit to the whole repo, without touching the file file1.txt.

```
    SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);       

    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(user,password);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

    ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor("comment" , null);
    editor.openRoot(-1);
    editor.openFile("file1.txt", -1);
    editor.changeFileProperty("file1.txt", "mypropertyname", SVNPropertyValue.create("myvalue"));
    editor.closeEdit();
```

Comment: btw, i had posted a similar question concerning changing properties of -DIRECTORIES- here, in case you wonder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469488/change-svn-directory-property-on-the-fly-with-svnkit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had not called closeFile(), and i needed an "/" before the filename, now it works

```
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);       

ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(user,password);
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor("comment" , null);
editor.openRoot(-1);
editor.openFile("/file1.txt", -1);
editor.changeFileProperty("/file1.txt", "mypropertyname", SVNPropertyValue.create("myvalue"));
editor.closeFile("/file1.txt",null);
editor.closeEdit();
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use
SVNDeltaGenerator and use sendDelta method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30306692)