# How to change a versioned svn property without changing/adding anything else in a repo?

Tags: svn, revision

I am the administrator of a very large, over 1.3 M revisions, SVN repo. I have to extract a large subset to create a new SVN repo and I can neither add new revisions to the original repo nor modify their dates. Yes, I need the complete history.
One of the revisions to extract has (no idea how it happened 15 years ago) a custom svn versioned property whose value has a "è" char encoded in ASCII (1 byte) and not in UTF-8 (2 bytes) as SVN expects the client should have properly encoded.
The tool I am using, Subdivision, correctly issues an error while processing that revision, as it finds bad property contents.
The svnadmin verify command on that revisions finds no error, but it does not look at the encoding used.

Using svn propset would create a new revision, with a new date, what I cannot allow; moreover it would not solve the problem, because the buggy revision remains the same.
The suggestion I am looking for is how to modify the revision file (<path_to_repo>/db/revs/Krevs/revno) in a way that keeps the repository coherent. The revision file has checksums and you can calculate them again, if you are sure of what is the precise set of characters to include.
It could be useful to reproduce the issue in a minimal repo just to test, but how to create a buggy revision? Copying the buggy revision file from the original to another simpler repo is complex, at least at first sight.
[change svn file property on the fly with svnkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607511/change-svn-file-property-on-the-fly-with-svnkit) suggests a way to change the value of the property, but it seems to ignore the checksums and the size of the property.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would it be an option to make a copy of the repo, modify the copy and then extract the subset from the copy?

Comment: @Friedrich: no, because in the subset I need to keep the original revno and date for all extracted revisions; the problem is how to change the repo without modifying anything else but that property

Comment: @bahrep: SVN has both versioned and unversioned properties; revision properties are indeed unversioned, whilst all other, including custom ones, are versioned

Comment: Note that the [red bean book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) even allows properties to be set to binary data. I doubt they need to be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Friedrich: https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.l10n.html says "The repository stores all paths, filenames, and log messages in Unicode, encoded as UTF-8. In that sense, the repository is internationalized—that is, the repository is ready to accept input in any human language. This means, however, that the Subversion client is responsible for sending only UTF-8 filenames and log messages into the repository. To do this, it must convert the data from the native locale into UTF-8."

Comment: Do you ask about "paths, filenames and log messages" (your comment) or about "a custom svn property" (your question)?

Comment: I am asking about a custom svn property, but I saw that with 2 different svn clients (i.e. CLI and TortoiseSVN) the property values are encoded as UTF-8; due to the fact that I cannot use svn propset to set a new value I am focusing on modifying the non UTF-8 value

Comment: I tell you why I am being such a pest. Are you familiar with the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? I may be wrong but I suspect X = "subdivision is failing" and Y = "how to retroactively change the encoding of an svn prop". Unfortunately, I am not familiar with subdivision. I'm surprised it would stumble on a Latin-1 string where arbitrary binary data is legal but I'm really out of my depth.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
It's not important, at the moment, decide if Subdivision tried to manage what had to be passed unchanged; I just wanted to modify the files representing the repository revisions in a way that any tool could find the repository consistent.
The versioned property contained an "è" that was in the revision file (<path_to_repo>/db/revs/Krevs/revno). I modified that file with a binary editor to change "è" to "e" and saved the file. The binary editor was chosen to avoid any other change.
Then I used svn propget to read that property at that revno;I got an error because the checksum was incorrect, but the error message told me what the checksum should be, so I used the binary editor again to change the checksum too and saved the file.
That made the revision file consistent and I had no more problems.